# Java array: strange behaviour

Tags: java, arrays

Everyone!
I faced this strange behaviour of Java arrays. I cannot figure out why sampleArray is changing along with class' array? I find this unnatural.

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int sampleArray[] = new int[]{5, -1, 9 ,7 ,3 ,2 ,11 ,0 ,-7 ,6 , 10 ,9};
            SortArray testArray = new SortArray(sampleArray);
            System.out.println("Initial array is:");
            System.out.println(testArray.toString());

            testArray.sortArray();
            System.out.println("Sorted by Bubbles method array is:");
            System.out.println(testArray.toString());
            System.out.println("Initial array is");
            for (int i = 0; i<sampleArray.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(sampleArray[i]+ " ");
            }
```

}

```
public class SortArray {
    private int anArray[];

    SortArray (int inputArray[]) {
         this.anArray = inputArray;
    }

    // Classic Bubbles sorting
    public void sortArray () {
            int arrayLength = this.anArray.length;
            for (int i = arrayLength; i > 0; i--) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                            if (anArray[j+1]<anArray[j]) {
                                    int tempVariable = anArray[j];
                                    anArray[j] = anArray[j+1];
                                    anArray[j+1] = tempVariable;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            String arrayString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i<anArray.length; i++) {
                    arrayString = arrayString + anArray[i]+" ";
            }
            return arrayString;
    }
```

}

After all I keep getting:

```
Initial array is:
5 -1 9 7 3 2 11 0 -7 6 10 9 
Sorted by Bubbles method array is:
-7 -1 0 2 3 5 6 7 9 9 10 11 
Initial array is
-7 -1 0 2 3 5 6 7 9 9 10 11 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

So we see that initial array is changing as well. Why is this happening? It seems to be illogical as I never assign sampeArray another sequence and never change it directly in the code. But it's true.
What to do in order to keep the initial array unaffected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using a reference to the original array :

```
this.anArray = inputArray;
```

Any modification of `anArray` , is in fact a modification of the original array (both variables refer to the exact same `Object`).

Other than that, you may use [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) .

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I have done to leave the initial array unaffected is to change the constructor:

```
SortArray (int inputArray[]) {
    this.anArray = inputArray.clone();
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12653706)

Comment: @JonasCz This **was** an answer. OP made a clone of the array to prevent the reference from being used.